# Why does import call give 'no module named ... found'?

Tags: python, import, python-3.11

writing code for assignment, game like Scrabble and for some reason the output says 'No modules named ps4a found'.

```
from ps4a import *
```

I checked and I have a python file named ps4a in the same folder as the one I'm coding in.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/12559207)

Comment: It's common to have this issues when we are importing libraries in Python. The names are very important to check so ensure the name is correct, or if you have the library locally check the path and ensure that it's correct.